# Supersolvable and pronormal subgroups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group such that all subgroups of prime-power order are pronormal in $G$. If $M$ is a normal $p$-subgroup of $G$ then all prime-power order subgroups of $G/M$ are pronormal in $G/M$.

I need to show that $G$ is supersolvable. The author  [ams.org/journals/proc/1969-020-01](http://%20ams.org/journals/proc/1969-020-01) says that it follows easily from the above but I'm not too familiar with the characterisations of finite supersolvable groups to get a conclusion from the hypothseis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should perhaps have mentioned that the author has already shown at this stage that $G$ is solvable.

Let $N$ be a minimal normal subgroup of $G$. Then, since $G$ is solvable,  $N$ is an elementary abelian $p$-group for some prime $p$. Let $M$ be a subgroup of $N$ of order $p$.

Then $M$ is pronormal in $G$ and, so for any $g \in G$, $M$ and $M^g$ are conjugate in $\langle M,M^g \rangle$. But $\langle M,M^g \rangle \le N$, which is abelian, so $M=M^g$ and $M \unlhd G$ (so in fact $N=M$).

Since all prime-power order subgroups of $G/M$ are pronormal in $G/M$, $G/M$ is supersolvable by induction. Hence $G$ is supersolvable.

Comment: This is a better way of proving it. Thanks. The author uses this fact to show $G$ is supersolvable:  If $H$ is a pronormal subgroup of $G$ with $H\leq K$ for a subgroup $K$ of $G$. Then $H$ is subnormal in $K$ $\iff$ $H\unlhd K$. Any idea why he used this than opposed to the method you have given?